# Argo CD - limit time for Application for transit to Degradated state

Tags: argocd

Here is common scenario we stuck with:

1. Argocd Application created and synced with Helm, it has deployment with 1 pod, all green.[image]
2. We updating deployment image tag with some broken value not exists in our Docker Image registry and push changes to git repo.
3. Argo pick up updates from git repo, sync status is green Synced state, but app health is "Processing" [image]
4. In result of change Deployment tries to roll out new pod with broken image tag, and obviusly not able to do it.
5. Agrocd App stuck in app health "Processing" state for about 10 minunes and eventually transit to "Degradated" state [image]

Now the questio, can we limit this time and have "Degradataed" state in 1 or 2 minutes instead 10?

Comment: Looks like the 2nd screenshot might be the wrong image?

Answer (score 0):

Do you create app with GUI or yaml file?
If you create app with yaml file you can do it by set field limit or maxDuration in retry.
Here is an example

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: guestbook
  # You'll usually want to add your resources to the argocd namespace.
  namespace: argocd
  # Add a this finalizer ONLY if you want these to cascade delete.
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  # The project the application belongs to.
  project: default

  # Source of the application manifests
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: guestbook

    # helm specific config
    helm:
      # Release name override (defaults to application name)
      releaseName: guestbook

      # Helm values files for overriding values in the helm chart
      # The path is relative to the spec.source.path directory defined above
      valueFiles:
      - values-prod.yaml

      # Optional Helm version to template with. If omitted it will fall back to look at the 'apiVersion' in Chart.yaml
      # and decide which Helm binary to use automatically. This field can be either 'v2' or 'v3'.
      version: v2

  # Destination cluster and namespace to deploy the application
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: guestbook

  # Sync policy
  syncPolicy:
    automated: # automated sync by default retries failed attempts 5 times with following delays between attempts ( 5s, 10s, 20s, 40s, 80s ); retry controlled using `retry` field.
      prune: true # Specifies if resources should be pruned during auto-syncing ( false by default ).
      selfHeal: true # Specifies if partial app sync should be executed when resources are changed only in target Kubernetes cluster and no git change detected ( false by default ).
      allowEmpty: false # Allows deleting all application resources during automatic syncing ( false by default ).
    syncOptions:     # Sync options which modifies sync behavior
    - Validate=false # disables resource validation (equivalent to 'kubectl apply --validate=false') ( true by default ).
    - CreateNamespace=true # Namespace Auto-Creation ensures that namespace specified as the application destination exists in the destination cluster.
    - PrunePropagationPolicy=foreground # Supported policies are background, foreground and orphan.
    - PruneLast=true # Allow the ability for resource pruning to happen as a final, implicit wave of a sync operation
    # The retry feature is available since v1.7
    retry:
      limit: 5 # number of failed sync attempt retries; unlimited number of attempts if less than 0
      backoff:
        duration: 5s # the amount to back off. Default unit is seconds, but could also be a duration (e.g. "2m", "1h")
        factor: 2 # a factor to multiply the base duration after each failed retry
        maxDuration: 3m # the maximum amount of time allowed for the backoff strategy
```

Comment: well the issue is that sync status is ok after apply, but I'll try it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not coming from ArgoCD as, as you mentioned it sync status is ok.

You may want to set `progressDeadlineSeconds` in your `Deployment` object